# php curl returning empty string

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a call to an API and POST some data. I'm getting the following response:

```
string '' (length=0).
```

Here is the code:

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    $subscriberEmail => $email,
    $subscriberJobType => $jobType,
    $subscriberLocation => $location
];

$ch = curl_init('https://URLTOEXTERNALSITE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: MY API KEY HERE', 'Content-Type: text/x-php-serialization'
    ));

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
die();
```

Why am I only getting an empty string returned?

**EDIT**

This is a JSON example from the API docs

```
$ curl -X POST EXTERNAL/URL/GOES/HERE -u $API_KEY: \

--form email=user1@domain1.com \
--form create_time='2012-05-03 09:45:23' \
--form search='Legal Assistant' \
--form location='Houston, TX' \
--form content-type=application/json
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Shoudnt you have in POSTFILEDS $subscriberInfo instead of $post?

Comment: @Deep - There isn't a recorded error

Comment: I added a JSON example above. This is from the API docs

Comment: Unrecorded error? Then try tcpflow/wireshark/other for check correct request-response. Or try make this request from cli curl with max verbose

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to call

> curl_exec($ch);

after

> $response = curl_exec($ch);

```
    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_exec($ch);

    // close the connection, release resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It's called here `$response = curl_exec($ch);`. No need to call it twice

Comment: @PaulDessert maybe he bulds up curl muscles ))

Comment: For example: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php\n$ch%20=%20curl_init(%27http://dilemink.com/%27);\ncurl_setopt($ch,%20CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,%20true);\n//curl_setopt($ch,%20CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,%20$post);\ncurl_setopt($ch,%20CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,%20array(\n%20%27Authorization:%20MY%20API%20KEY%20HERE%27,%20%27Content-Type:%20text/x-php-serialization%27\n%20));\n\n//%20execute!\n$response%20=%20curl_exec($ch);\ncurl_exec($ch);\n//%20close%20the%20connection,%20release%20resources\ncurl_close($ch);\n\n//var_dump($response);\necho%20$response;\ndie();\n\n?%3E\n